# how to get rid of the sin I committed?

Tags: life, afterlife, sin

(What if) I realized I had committed a sin and now I fear after the outcome of it? 
I fear it will definitely bring sorrow at some point of my life/ in course of life cycles.  
How do I get relieved from this fear factor? 

My thoughts are now filled with fear than feeling repent/paschatap!

Comment: no words to say! how can you judge it as duplicate, wont you mind on dropping a comment!

Comment: I am nobody to advice anybody, so please do not take this as an advice. But here is some food for thought. It is true that the sin committed has to be reaped. But remember the story of Sri Parikshit. He was doomed to die a horrible death bitten by a snake on account of curse due throwing a snake on a sadhu. But He accepted His fate and decided that he will spend His days by thinking about God and remembering His Lilas. What we can learn from that story? Even if we have done great sins, and have to reap them, but still let us continue our Sadhana. let us earnestly and sincerely aspire for God

Comment: God will liberate the One who shows sincerity. There is not a single human being in this world who is free from sin. But the one who strives sincerely to achieve God, is liberated from all sin. Remember Sri Krishna's words 'Surrender to Me, and I will free you from all sinful reactions'. Surrender to Him by bhakti, jnana or karma yoga. The path is immaterial. The goal is the same. All rivers merge in the ocean. All roads lead to the same goal sir. Change from 'sin' to 'sin-cere'. God resides in all Hearts. Therefore let us sincere and not criticize other beliefs. Thank you. All the best!!